# How to order WPF tag attributes consistently

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, code-readability

While working with WPF I switch between XAML and the designer. This causes the attributes on each element to be ordered differently and makes the code harder to read unless I go though and reorder everything manually.

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
<TextBox Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=Default}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,2,31,11" Grid.Row="5" />

<TextBox Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=LastName, Mode=Default}" Margin="6,0,31,4" Name="txtLastName" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [XAML Styler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3de2a3c6-def5-42c4-924d-cc13a29ff5b7) extension to format my XAML files.  It automatically sorts attributes by a configurable priority and does some other nice formatting for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Visual Studio's [Document Outline window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28VS.80%29.aspx) (in View - Other Windows). It shows the document structure as a tree and allows you to quickly position into any element, so maybe it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you using the following configuration for XAML Styler:

1. Download the Xaml Styler extension for VS 2022
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler
2. Save the code bellow in a file called Settings.XamlStyler and put it on the same folder of your solution (.sln) file.

```json
    {
        "AttributesTolerance": 1,
        "KeepFirstAttributeOnSameLine": true,
        "MaxAttributeCharactersPerLine": 0,
        "MaxAttributesPerLine": 1,
        "NewlineExemptionElements": "RadialGradientBrush, GradientStop, LinearGradientBrush, ScaleTransform, SkewTransform, RotateTransform, TranslateTransform, Trigger, Condition, Setter",
        "SeparateByGroups": false,
        "AttributeIndentation": 0,
        "AttributeIndentationStyle": 0,
        "RemoveDesignTimeReferences":  false,
        "IgnoreDesignTimeReferencePrefix": false,
        "EnableAttributeReordering": true,
        "FirstLineAttributes": "x:Class, Grid.Row, Grid.Column, Grid.RowSpan, Grid.ColumnSpan, DockPanel.Dock, Orientation",
        "AttributeOrderingRuleGroups": [
            "d:DataContext",
            "xmlns, xmlns:x",
            "xmlns:*",
            "x:Key, Key, x:Name, Name, x:Uid, Uid, Title",
            "x:Class, Grid.Row, Grid.Column, Grid.RowSpan, Grid.ColumnSpan, DockPanel.Dock, Orientation",
            "Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Canvas.Right, Canvas.Bottom",
            "DataContext, Text, Content, Source, Command, CommandParameter, ItemSource, ItemsSource",
            "DisplayMemberPath, SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedIndex",
            "Margin, Padding, HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, HorizontalContentAlignment, VerticalContentAlignment, Panel.ZIndex",
            "Width, Height, MinWidth, MinHeight, MaxWidth, MaxHeight",
            "UpImageSource, DownImageSource",
            "IsEnabled, Visibility",
            "*:*, *",
            "PageSource, PageIndex, Offset, Color, TargetName, Property, Value, StartPoint, EndPoint",
            "mc:Ignorable, d:IsDataSource, d:LayoutOverrides, d:IsStaticText",
            "Storyboard.*, From, To, Duration"
        ],
        "OrderAttributesByName": true,
        "PutEndingBracketOnNewLine": false,
        "RemoveEndingTagOfEmptyElement": true,
        "SpaceBeforeClosingSlash": true,
        "RootElementLineBreakRule": 0,
        "ReorderVSM": 1,
        "ReorderGridChildren": false,
        "ReorderCanvasChildren": false,
        "ReorderSetters": 3,
        "FormatMarkupExtension": false,
        "NoNewLineElements": "RadialGradientBrush, GradientStop, LinearGradientBrush, ScaleTransform, SkewTransform, RotateTransform, TranslateTransform, Trigger, Condition, Setter, Style",
        "NoNewLineMarkupExtensions": "x:Bind, Binding",
        "ThicknessSeparator": 2,
        "ThicknessAttributes": "Margin, Padding, BorderThickness, ThumbnailClipMargin",
        "PutAttributeOrderRuleGroupsOnSeparateLines": false,
        "FormatOnSave": true,
        "CommentPadding": 2,
        "SaveAndCloseOnFormat": true }
```

3. Right click a Xaml file or the entire project and click "Format XAML" to have your files correctly formatted.

This configuration will also auto format any xaml file on Save.

It also works with .NET MAUI and probably with UWP and WinUI.